# CSSで、ドキュメントルートより上に配置しているSVGタグそのものを読み込む方法はありますか？

Tags: php, css, svg

#### 現状

ドキュメントルートより上に、(実質的にはsvgである)hoge.phpを配置しています。
出力したい箇所(html)で、hoge.phpを読み込み、svgを表示しています。

hoge.php

```
<svg height="" viewBox="" width="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d=""/></svg>
```

index.html

```
<?php include('hoge.php'); ?>
```

#### やりたいこと

CSSで、hoge.phpを読み込み、SVG表示したい

#### 試したこと

index.html

```
<style>
.test:before {
    background-image: url("<?php include('hoge.php'); ?>");
```

invalid property errorになりました。

`background-image: url(ファイルパス/ファイル名.svg);` にする必要があるからだと思うのですが、

- svgタグそのものを読み込んで表示する方法はありますか？
- あるいは、PHPで疑似的にSVGファイルを出力したように見せかけ、そのファイルパスを指定するようなことはできますか？
- そもそもの大前提として、background-image: url()で、ドキュメントルートより上に配置しているファイルを指定することはできますか？

Comment: 一般的な PHPはサーバーサイドで動作するけど, サーバーの話ですか？もしもクライアント側なら, JavaScriptで動かせる PHPが存在するかもだけど, その場合 JavaScript/TypeScriptで行うほうがたぶん簡単。

Comment: サーバーの話です。本文に追記しました。

Comment: 「ドキュメントルートより上のファイルが参照できるか」と「SVG として出力する PHP を CSS で読み込む」は分けて考えるべきじゃないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文の2番目の方法が実現できます。
質問文の様な`hoge.php`が存在するとして、ヘッダに`Content-type`を適切にセットすればphpファイルも画像扱いになります。
すなわち、

```php
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
?>
<svg height="" viewBox="" width="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d=""/></svg>
```

（当然ですがsvgタグの内容は単体でsvgファイルとして適切なフォーマットである必要があります）
あとはCSSのbackground-imageでphpファイルを直接指定すれば良いです。

```html
<style>
.test:before {
    background-image: url(./hoge.php);
    （以下省略）
```

###### 補足

ドキュメント中の要素をIDで指定して背景にしてしまう`element`という指定も仕様で勧告されていますが対応しているのは2021年現在firefoxのみです。
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element()

Comment: 参考までに「header 'Content-Type」をどうやって調べるのか知りたいのですが、例えば「image/svg+xml」をどこで確認するのですか？　「https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type」「https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7233#section-4.1」「https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5」に記載されていないのは、SVGが新しいからですか？　「https://triple-underscore.github.io/SVG11/mimereg.html」を見てMIME メディア型を個別に確認する感じですか？

Comment: 尤も確実な情報源は[IANAが公開しているmedia-typeの一覧](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)です。MDNの[MIME タイプ (IANA メディアタイプ)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)も参考にしてください。

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございました。こんなページがあることを初めて知りました。「header 'Content-Type」というよりは「Media Types」として仕様が公開されているのですね。